# Strange JavaScript Regular Expression Behavior

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting different behavior from a regular expression in JavaScript depending on whether or not I declare it using literal syntax.  Using a extremely simple test HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var s = '3';
            var regex1 = /\d/;
            var regex2 = new RegExp('\d');

            alert(s.search(regex1)); //  0 (matches)
            alert(s.search(regex2)); // -1 (does not match)
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The regular expression declared with literal syntax (`/\d/`) works correctly, while the other (`new RegExp('\d')`) does not.  Why on earth is this happening?

I'm using Google Chrome 5.0.375.70 on Windows Vista Home Premium, if that's at all helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using strings, `\d` is a special character. You need to escape the backslash:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp('\\d');
```

See [String Literals](http://mzl.la/bYxuM5):

> ### Escaping Characters
>
> For characters not listed in Table
>   2.1, a preceding backslash is ignored, but this usage is deprecated and
>   should be avoided.

So basically '`\d`' is treated as `'d'`, which is why it doesn't match. For example:

```
alert('d'.search(new RegExp('\d'))); // 0 (matches!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex2 = new RegExp('\\d');
```

works for me.